# time not synching properly in windows server environment

Tags: time, active-directory, operating-system, windows-server-2008

I got 2* windows members servers 2016...
got 2*AD's = AD1 has pdc ..
AD1 & AD2 time are same.
AD2 syncs time to use AD1.
both member servers sync time to AD2
above is the setup

both member servers synching to AD2.
but member1 time = got 10AM & member2 time = got 10:10AM  ...
AD1 & AD2 = 10:08AM

how to fix this ?? why member server time differs to AD2